# Error 3 while compiling C++ project in Qt

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator

When I try to compile a very simple C++ project (no code related to QT) in Qt Creator (Qt Creator 4.14.2, Based on Qt 5.15.2), it shows Error 3 in the issues tab.

I have no idea what is wrong, my previous basic projects worked fine. I also checked Projects -> Build Environment -> Clear system environment

Below is the compile output.

```
00:58:00: Running steps for project Network...
00:58:00: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
00:58:00: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j2
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/antiq/Documents/QT/build-Network-Desktop_Qt_6_0_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../Network -I. -IC:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/DataStructure.o ../Network/DataStructure.cpp
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../Network -I. -IC:/Qt/6.0.3/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/main.o ../Network/main.cpp
Cannot create temporary file in C:\WINDOWS\: Permission denied
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:108: debug/DataStructure.o] Error 3
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Cannot create temporary file in C:\WINDOWS\: Permission denied
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:111: debug/main.o] Error 3
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/antiq/Documents/QT/build-Network-Desktop_Qt_6_0_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: debug] Error 2
00:58:03: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Network (kit: Desktop Qt 6.0.3 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
00:58:03: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

Comment: `Cannot create temporary file in C:\WINDOWS\: Permission denied` That's probably your problem. You need to figure out what's trying to write to the windows folder, which by default requires elevated permissions

Comment: I would guess there's a `TEMP` environment variable pointing to `C:\WINDOWS\`. Please check and possibly reconfigure.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?